# Row colored with alternatingly with \taburowcolors is pink

Tags: tables, color, tabu

I'm making a table with `tabu` having alternating row color, but I'm getting a pink row, which is not a color that I defined.

The code:

```
\definecolor{lightb}{RGB}{217,224,250}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries}lX[l]}
        \toprule
        \taburowcolors{lightb..white}
        Row1 & #1 \\
        Row2 & #2 \\
        Row3 & #3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

And the result:

[image: output]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because tabu does not use “real” alternate colors but colorseries provided by package `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\definecolor{lightb}{RGB}{217,224,250}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries}lX[l]}
        \toprule
        \taburowcolors[1]3{lightb..white}
        Row1 & 1 \\
        Row2 & 2 \\
    Row3 & 3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing to `\taburowcolors[1]4{lightb..white}` gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\definecolor{lightb}{RGB}{217,224,250}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries}lX[l]}
        \toprule
        \taburowcolors[1]4{lightb..white}
        Row1 & 1 \\
        Row2 & 2 \\
    Row3 & 3 \\
    Row4 & 4 \\
    Row5 & 5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Coloring with `table` option of `xcolor`

If you want alternating rows between two colors (lightb and white) as said in the comment, you may go with `xcolor` and its table coloring.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
%\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
%\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
%\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\definecolor{lightb}{RGB}{217,224,250}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{lightb}{white}%
    \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries}lX[l]}
        \toprule
        %\taburowcolors[1]4{lightb..white}
        Row1 & 1 \\
        Row2 & 2 \\
    Row3 & 3 \\
    Row4 & 4 \\
    Row5 & 5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but if I want alternating rows between two colors (lightb and white) ?

Comment: Are there big differences?

Comment: @regisk7: See the update using `xcolor`.